# displaying an image in a qlabel which has been promoted to a class

Tags: qt, qtgui, qpixmap, qlabel

I'm writing a gui application and I must display an image on a label that has been promoted into a class(my_qlabel). I upload the image using a dialog in the other class, and call a function in "my_qlabel" to display it.

```
void my_qlabel::displayImage(QString filename){
     QPixmap pic (filename);
     //..i dont know the relevant lines i should include here to display....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLabel` class has a [`setPixmap(const QPixmap &)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) function. Since you are subclassing `QLabel` class, you can use the same function in your class.

```
void my_qlabel::displayImage(QString filename){
    QPixmap pic (filename);
    setPixmap(pic);
}
```